# Cosa vuol dire "abbrivare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Non c’era nessuno delle parti del Pavaglione che potessi dirmelo amico, ma non avevo neanche dei nemici, salvo forse un balordo che senza avanzar niente da me e soltanto per far lo spiritoso m’aveva attaccato una festa a Manera, ma m’**abbrivò** solo a parole.

Ho cercato il verbo "abbrivare" in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso nel contesto del brano. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Direi che il significato è minacciare. Fu minacciato solo a parole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In un numero del giornale l'[Alassino](http://www.vecchiaalassio.it/Pdf/2010/09.pdf), ho trovato un significato per abbrivare:

> Ad esempio, è facile comprendere come il verbo “**abbrivare**”, nato in
>   Provenza, voglia significare “mettersi in movimento” ed indica proprio
>   il procedere della nave che, lasciando gli ormeggi ed il porto,
>   comincia a prendere l’abbrivo, cioè la spinta necessaria per
>   acquistare velocità. Tuttavia questo verbo, giunto dalle nostre parti,
>   oltre che al significato naturale, nel nostro dialetto ha assunto una
>   connotazione del tutto nuova e diversa. Chiedetelo ai giovanotti
>   alassini. Piuttosto focosi quando abbordano, senza violenza,
>   naturalmente, una bella ragazza... “**U l’ha abbrivò**!”, le è saltato
>   addosso come un falco, ma graziosamente e solo per corteggiarla

Nel contesto da te citato abbrivare ha il significato di assalire, saltare addosso, importunare.

Il termine viene usato con questo significato sia in Piemonte che in Liguria.